# Can the insulation in an oven be dried out?

Tags: appliances

We bought a used stove, evidently a hose was used to clean it before listing.  There are some areas that are soaking wet, other areas damp.  And would it be safe to use?

Comment: I would try to get the money back.  Water and electricity does not mix well and could kill.  Water/moisture causes rust/corrosion which is not good either.  A good object to scrape to the landfill.

Comment: Depends on what got wet. If just *thermal* insulation (e.g., fiberglass batting around oven only), it might dry successfully after a use or two. If a circuit board, switch or thin iron parts were soaked, I'd have second thoughts...

Comment: Pull it out and leave it out in the sun for a few days?

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote "Depends on what got wet. If just thermal insulation (e.g., fiberglass batting around oven only), it might dry successfully after a use or two. If a circuit board, switch or thin iron parts were soaked, I'd have second thoughts.. DrMoishe Pippik"

This for sure..

I wouldn't ever buy an appliance that's been hosed down. But, you may not have known this before you bought it..
If you bought from a store, I would return it

Comment: What and who did you intend to quote here?